# Should I keep my Streams for multiple operations?

Tags: java, stream, byte

I have the following method to compress a bytearray.

```
protected byte[] compress(byte[] original)
{
   byte[] compressed = null;
   try (ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
   {
      try (DeflaterOutputStream stream = new DeflaterOutputStream(buffer, new Deflater()))
      {
         stream.write(original);
      }
      compressed = buffer.toByteArray();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
return compressed;
}
```

Now I am wondering if the performance cost for constantly reinitializing the streams is high and how I could keep the streams in my class.

Are there any downsides to doing that?

Specifically in the context of threads.

Comment: Until performance has shown it's a problem, it's not a problem. Write code that's easy to read.

Comment: Try the New I/O (NIO) from JDK7, should make it easier.